# I am getting this http://onclickrev.com redirects from chrome and mozilla

Tags: malware, antivirus

I am getting this `http://onclickrev.com` redirects from Chrome and Mozilla Firefox when ever I view sites that are not secured connects - like http:/******.com and the CPU usage goes above 60%. Is there any solution to this?

I have run my system clean using ClamTk but not found anything suspicious.

Comment: This is most likely your ISP or the wifi you're connecting to, injecting javascript.

Comment: yes, my wifi router was having a DNS address that was doing this, made the change to 8.8.8.8 and all is good now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that you dns server is causing the redirection. Change your dns servers to google's and see if it fixes the issue:

`sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`

and paste into it

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment (put # in front off) any other entries except the two lines above

save the file with **ctrl+o** then exit with **ctrl+x**

The changes take effect immediately so no need for other settings

Comment: You may want to preserve whatever is in there already as forensic evidence, in case a program has been tampering with the DNS settings.